# How to replace @SpringBootTest on @ContextConfiguration (Java Spring)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the test class, with @SpringBootTest:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnviroment = SpringBootTest.WebEnviroment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = App.class)
public class MyTest {
...
}
```

I need to replace @SpringBootTest, on @ContextConfiguration, and i do it:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "my.xml", initializers = MyTest.MockJee.class)
public class MyTest {
...
}
```

But @SpringBootTest has parameter, which @ContextConfigruration hasn't:

```
webEnviroment = SpringBootTest.WebEnviroment.RANDOM_PORT
```

So if i can join @SpringBootTest and @ContextConfiguration, it will be nice. But SpringBootTest + ContextConfiguration create conflict (they create context both), so this is reason why i want to replace SpringBootTest.
Question: How to make like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "my.xml", initializers = MyTest.MockJee.class, webEnviroment = SpringBootTest.WebEnviroment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MyTest {
...
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with some information about why you want to make this change? Are you moving from Spring Boot to plain Spring Framework or is there another reason for not using `@SpringBootTest` any more?

Comment: I do it, because if i use SpringBootTest + ContextConfiguration create conflict, so this is reason why i want to replace SpringBootTest

Comment: If you're still using Spring Boot, I think you'd be better addressing that conflict rather than ditching `@SpringBootTest`.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you are trying to achieve.
But one of the effects of using `SpringBootTest.WebEnviroment.RANDOM_PORT` is to actually set the property `server.port` to 0.